# Empty output for NLTK function in CGI script

Tags: python, nltk, cgi, tokenize

I want to use python NLTK library's function in CGI script to tokenize some text, recieved via WEB.

If i simply use:

```py
someamountoftext = "someamountoftext someamountoftext someamountoftext"
```

and then

```py
 nltk.word_tokenize(someamountoftext)
```

or

```py
nltk.sent_tokenize(someamountoftext)
```

It will work.

BUT! If I use this:

```py
#!C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe
import os
import urllib.parse
import nltk
query_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(os.environ['QUERY_STRING'])

def tknz_wrd(someamountoftext):
return(nltk.word_tokenize(someamountoftext))


print("Content-Type: text/html\n")

print (tknz_wrd(someamountoftext))
```

(Above is all my code of sigle file, no frameworks or something).

It does not print anything on screen. No erros, just white browser screen.
Ofcourse, I tried manual input like:

http://localhost/speciallocationforproject/local/tokenize/morgot.py?someamountoftext=somekindoftext

It did not change anything.

morgot.py - name of my CGI file.

Where is my mistake? And\or how  to make tokenization via WEB?

I use: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.28

python 3.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
So i made few mistakes, and the correct code is:

```py
#!C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe

import os
import urllib.parse
import nltk

query_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(os.environ[‘QUERY_STRING’])
input_something = str(query_dict[‘someamountoftext’])[2: -2]
def tknz_wrd(someamountoftext):
return(nltk.word_tokenize(someamountoftext))

print(“Content-Type: text/html\n”)

print (tknz_wrd(input_something))
```

It processes data, recieved from browser line, like:
http://localhost/speciallocation/local/tokenize/morgot.py?someamountoftext=Enter%20your%20text%20here

morgot.py - name of CGI file.

'?someamountoftext=' This is how you enter data into variable

%20 - spacebar in browser line.

Output:
['Enter', 'your', 'text', 'here']